# NSDateFormater does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a piece of code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
NSString *strDate = @"07/02/2015 17:41:22";
NSDate *startTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strDate];
```

Why does startTime equal nil?

Comment: Because your format doesn't match your date string. Look in the spec for the proper format for 24-hour formats.

Comment: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date%5FFormat%5FPatterns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date is 24hrs format, so you have to use `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `HH` (for hour [0-23]) and not `hh` (for [1-12])

Answer (score 0):

In NSDateformatter HH:mm:ss is used for 24 hour format , while hh:mm:ss is used for 12 hour format .

And as you have used hh:mm:ss in your code which is 12 hour Format , and strDate is using 24 hours format. That's the Problem use HH:mm:ss instead.